# Leaflet.js heatmap.js - window resize event

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, heatmap

I am using [heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/index.html) for plotting heatmaps on leaflet.js. I am able to render it beautifully. However lets say the initial window/div size is 400x400. Then I resize the window and the div becomes 600x600, the heatmap layer is still sized at 400x400 and cuts-off. When you move the map, you can see the chopped 400x400 area of heatmap.

Anyway to resize or reset the size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen to the `resize` event of your `L.Map` instance:

> Fired when the map is resized.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-resize

Then use the `invalideSize` method of the `L.Map` instance:

> Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so — call it after you've changed the map size dynamically,

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize

```
map.on('resize', function () {
    map.invalidateSize();
});
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. It was a good start. But I had to add remove the heatmap layer and redraw it again for it to work. I am accepting your answer and posted my answer as well.

Comment: @ih8 I have my heatmap in a hidden div. When I open the hidden div the map is shown but alsmost all of the div is grey not showing the map. I have to drag the map to see it or change my screen size then the map is shown. Can you tell me how will I  to see the map correctly when the hidden div becomes visible

Comment: map correctly loads only when I resize the browser or open my browser console

Comment: @Gardezi, did you even read my answer? You can do so by calling `invalidateSize` on your map instance, just like i did in my code example. If you're having problems, please post your own question because this is absolutely not what the comments are meant for.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is a bug in leaflet 0.7.x, which occurs under certain CSS settings for the div containing the map. I got this fixed by modifying the following function in leaflet-heatmap.js:

```
_resetOrigin: function () {
  this._origin = this._map.layerPointToLatLng(new L.Point(0, 0));

  var size = this._map.getSize();
  if (this._width !== size.x || this._height !== size.y) {
    this._width  = size.x;
    this._height = size.y;

    this._el.style.width = this._width + 'px';
    this._el.style.height = this._height + 'px';
    this._heatmap._renderer.setDimensions(this._width, this._height);   // <- added this line
  }
  this._draw();
}
```